# Display database fields using first,1,2,..., last

Tags: php

Im trying to figure out how to achieve this:

http://t-webdesign.co.uk/projects/geusa/industry_jobs.html

Evenutually there will be lots of job postings under different industries, what would be the best way of implementing the 'page' links so i can display just 7 or 8 jobs at a time?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you implement pagination in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267892/how-do-you-implement-pagination-in-php)

Comment: possible duplicate of 500 other questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[You can use a pagination class for that.](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/4318-PHP-Split-MySQL-query-result-listings.html)**