# how to split mysql row

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you implement pagination in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267892/how-do-you-implement-pagination-in-php)

how to split mysql row?
i have 12 row in my table then i want to display first 4 row and next display 4 row
how to use please tell

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM myTable LIMIT 4;
SELECT * FROM myTable LIMIT 4,4;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT 0, 4
```

This will display the first 4 results from the database.

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT 7, 11
```

This will show records 8, 9, 10, 11.

Answer (score 0):

Use the SQL LIMIT clause:

```
SELECT ... LIMIT offset, max-result-set-size;
```

So, for the first 'page' you'd want LIMIT 0, 4, and then subsequently increment the offset by 4, eg:

```
LIMIT 0, 4
LIMIT 4, 4
LIMIT 8, 4
```

More information is available in the mySQL documentation...

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you want to display all of these sections at once, only with a visual divider:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$numberRows = 1;

while ($row) {

  if (($numberRows % 4) == 0) {
    echo "<hr>";
  }

  // display whatever $row data you need to
  var_dump($row);

  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
  $numberRows++;
}
```