# Pagination for PHP search results

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

How can i format pages in following manner?
eg my search results gave me data for 50 pages. then i want this format for pages.

> page1 page2 page3 page4 page5 .... page50

also when i click on '....' the result should be returned from page6 and the page listing should be like

> page1 .... page5 page6 page7 page8 page9 .... page50

i hope i am clear with my question

Comment: What specifically do you want help with? Writing an SQL query that returns results for a specific page? Finding out how many pages there are altogether? Calculating which page numbers should be displayed and which should be replaced by `...`? Creating the HTML and CSS for your page layout? Creating a link that makes a new request? What have you got so far and why doesn't it work?

Comment: Take a look of this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267892/how-do-you-implement-pagination-in-php regards.

Comment: That's a clever and minimalistic way to solve pagination :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://phpeasystep.com/phptu/29.html

Answer (score 0):

First calculate total number of records with its search criteria. 
Then divide it with record per page. 
So you will get Total Pages to show. 
say for eg

```
$total_number_record = 30; 
$record_per_page = 10; 
$total_pages = 30/10; (3)
```

Now use loop to show links

```
for($i=1;$i<=$total_pages;$i++){ 

    echo '<a href=\'search.php?page="'.$i.'"&search="'. $_POST['search'].'">Page '.$i.'</a>';

}
```

this will shows link on your web page

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find all answers on this page:

http://phpeasystep.com/phptu/29.html