# pagination in php

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

want search result for displaying exactly same result as in : https://www.ippu.purdue.edu/GlobalLinkages/index.cfm?Location=.&Page=search

1 - 25 of 414 records   Next >

I am using 3 inputs frm user ant it is same as link provided above

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pagination for PHP search results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244006/pagination-for-php-search-results)

Answer (score 1):

Use MySQL's LIMIT and OFFSET constructs:

```
$offset = ($current_page - 1) * $items_per_page;
// in your query:
LIMIT $items_per_page OFFSET $offset
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd check out the [Pager](http://pear.php.net/package/Pager) class in the PEAR repository. It's what I use for this sort of thing, and it has a bunch of options you can set.