# Implementing pagination in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

How to implement a pagination in this code:

```
<?php
    include "connect.php";
    $query  = mysql_query("SELECT username, date FROM users ORDER BY id ASC");
    while($row  = mysql_fetch_array($query)):
?>
        <div><h5><?php echo $row['username']; ?> (<?php echo $row['date']; ?>)</h5></div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of A LOT of questions

Comment: possible duplicate of [pagination in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857663/pagination-in-php)

Answer (score 3):

The idea is to play with mysql `LIMIT` keyword. It lets you limit the number of results you will get from mysql.

```
SELECT data FROM table LIMIT 5
```

is equivalent to

```
SELECT data FROM table LIMIT 0, 5
```

Where 0 is the offset and 5 the number of row returned by MySQL.

So you have to fix a number of item to display, let's say `$numRes = 10` and a page number:

```
if (isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page']))
     $page = $_GET['page'];
else
     $page = 0;
```

So you request is something like:

```
sprintf($request, "SELECT data FROM pages LIMIT %d, %d", $page, $numRes);
```

Comment: Is the offset the page number or the starting value, as in (page number * $numRes)?

Comment: this is the starting value, as your formule describes @Flipper.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Pagination
{
    public $cur_page;
    public $total;
    public $per_page;

    function __construct($cur_page, $total, $per_page)
    {
        $this->cur_page = $cur_page;
        $this->total = $total;
        $this->per_page = $per_page;
    }

    function getTotalPage(){
        return ceil($this->total / $this->per_page);
    }

    function hasPrevPage(){
        if($this->cur_page > 1){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    function hasNextPage(){
        if($this->cur_page < $this->getTotalPage()){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    function offSet(){
        return ($this->cur_page - 1) * $this->per_page;
    }
}

$total = 12;
$per_page = 5;
$cur_page = 1;

$pagination = new Pagination($cur_page, $total, $per_page);
$offSet = $pagination->offSet();
$query = "SELECT username, date FROM users ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT {$offset}, {$per_page}";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    require_once "connect.php";
    define('PER_PAGE',5);
    if (isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page'])):  // in your href use "domain.com/index.php?page=1"
        $start = $_GET['page_name'] * PER_PAGE;
        $query  = mysql_query("SELECT username, date FROM users ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT {$start},{$per_page}"); // where to start and for how many 1-5
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)): ?>
            <div><h5><?php echo $row['username']; ?> (<?php echo $row['date']; ?>)</h5></div>
            <?php
        endwhile;
    endif;
?>
```

Comment: but how can I change the page number without the url

Answer (score 0):

Pagination in PHP/MySQL is simply attained by using the `LIMIT` clause.

Initially you have to count the total records and divide it by the records per page. Pass the page number along with REQUEST.

Read the page number from the REQUEST array and find out the starting record of the page.

You can further read and see the complete implementation on the following page http://www.csnotes32.com/2014/11/page-wise-or-paginated-listing-of-data.html

Answer (score 0):

This is code for pagination. Use this with your database and you will get Google style pagination:

```
 <?php

  $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ui");


  $start=0;
   $limit=5;

      $t=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from form_table");
      $total=mysqli_num_rows($t);



       if(isset($_GET['id']))
       {
            $id=$_GET['id'] ; 
                            $start=($id-1)*$limit;

                              }
                else
                {
            $id=1;
   }
     $page=ceil($total/$limit);

       $query=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from form_table limit                                        $start,$limit");
     ?>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet"       href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script s        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">     </script>
     <script                    src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">          </script>
      </head>         
     <body>

    <div class="container">
     <h2>Table</h2>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
           <th>Id</th>
             <th>Name</th>
           <th>Gender</th>


    <th>Hobbies</th>
    <th>Course</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
    <tbody>

<?php
while($ft=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{?>
 <tr>
    <td><?= $ft['0']?></td>
    <td><?= $ft['1']?></td>
    <td><?= $ft['2']?></td>
    <td><?= $ft['3']?></td>
    <td><?= $ft['4']?></td>
  </tr>
<?php
}

?>


</tbody>
  </table>
     <ul class="pagination">
 <?php if($id > 1) {?> <li><a href="?id=<?php echo ($id-1) ?       >">Previous</a></li><?php }?>
 <?php
 for($i=1;$i <= $page;$i++){
 ?>
    <li><a href="?id=<?php echo $i ?>"><?php echo $i;?></a></li>
  <?php
 }
  ?>
<?php if($id!=$page)
//3!=4
{?>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is code for pagination in php##

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" id="font-awesome-style-css" href="https://www.phpflow.com/code/css/bootstrap3.min.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<!-- jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<title>phpflow.com : Source code of simaple ajax pagination</title>
</head>
<body>
<div><h3>Source code : PHP simaple ajax pagination</h1></div>
<div>
<div id="target-content" >loading...</div>

<?php
include('db.php'); 
$limit = 4;
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM coffee";  
$rs_result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);  
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($rs_result);  
$total_records = $row[0];  
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / $limit); 
?>
<div align="center">
<ul id="pagination">
<?php if(!empty($total_pages)):for($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++):  
      if($i == 1):?>
            <h3 class='active'  id="<?php echo $i;?>" style="float: left;"><a href='pagination.php?page=<?php echo $i;?>' ><?php echo $i;?></a></h3> 
      <?php else:?>
      <h3 id="<?php echo $i;?>" style="float: left;"><a href='pagination.php?page=<?php echo $i;?>'><?php echo $i;?></a></h3>
    <?php endif;?>      
<?php endfor;endif;?>  
</div>
</div>
</body>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery("#target-content").load("pagination.php?page=1");
    jQuery("#pagination h3").live('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
    jQuery("#target-content").html('loading...');
    jQuery("#pagination h3").removeClass('active');
    jQuery(this).addClass('active');
        var pageNum = this.id;
        jQuery("#target-content").load("pagination.php?page=" + pageNum);
    });
    });
</script>
```

##

Comment: This is a working code pagination in php using mysql you can change acoordingly your tables