# How to get the next record in a MySQL table with multiple sort values

Tags: mysql, sorting

Suppose I had a table with 5 fields or so and I wanted the next record but I want it to be the next one as if the records were ordered by 3 of the fields, as seen in the MySQL statement below:

```
SELECT id FROM t1 ORDERBY f1 ASC, f2 ASC, f3 ASC;
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean, "next record"? If you're doing a select, just do another fetch call and you'd get the next record.

Comment: @DeviantSeev Basically, I have a table with 100 or so records.  When I list the records on a web page, I have them sorted as I have in the MySql call I have listed above: they are sorted via 3 of the fields.  I want it so if I am on an individual page for one of the records, that it links to the next one in the sorted list.

Comment: @Manny: use a `limit` clause, and keep track of row numbers (not ids) so you can easily change your limit offsets to move forward/backwards in the query.

Comment: @Marc B could you give me an example??

Comment: @Manny: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489988/pagination-in-php

Comment: Is there a way of doing it strictly in MySQL?

Comment: @Manny the problem is that MySQL just returns the data based on your query. One thing you can do is write a stored procedure which takes in a row number as a parameter and returns the data based on that number. You can read about stored procedures here: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure-tutorial.aspx Then you can combine that stored procedure with the example which Marc gave you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution: By using Concat_ws of the two fields in both the WHERE (to select the next one) and the ORDER BY Clauses.