# How to create simple pagination based on DIV using PHP

Tags: php, pagination

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you implement pagination in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267892/how-do-you-implement-pagination-in-php)

Hi all,

How to create simple pagination based on DIV using PHP,

For example,

test1

test2

........test100

Kindly provide some example link. If possible ,please explain with example.

Thanks in advance,

Dinesh Kumar Manoharan

Comment: Many more here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+pagination

Comment: But he wants it based on DIV! ????

Answer (score 0):

maybe https://github.com/infinitas/infinitas/blob/beta/views/elements/pagination/admin/navigation.ctp