# Is there any framework in php to handle pagination?

Tags: php, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you implement pagination in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267892/how-do-you-implement-pagination-in-php)

Objective :

- Input : A JSON URL (in this case ,a facebook json)
- Output : The complete JSON (neatly stitched together)
- Process : It gets the json url, fetches the datd, proceeds to the    "next" "page", fetches the       data to the former data ....
  does    this till the end.

If there is no framework, can you help me with the code?

Comment: research pagination classes. There are a ton of them

Comment: Problem: Too wide-scoped, and not exactly a question - might get closed soon..

Comment: @Paul .  The answers I found from google, pagniation classes, pager all seem to tell me how to do pagination for my data... I need the reverse.... how to get data from pages .... and store in a single source.  Can any one tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bundle for SF2 FrameWork
https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle

Download the FW @ :
http://symfony.com/